# Yii2: display associative array

Tags: php, arrays, gridview, yii2, output

What is the easiest way to display an associative array in a table style?

The array is defined as

```
$data = [ 'name' => 'bert', 'age' => 42 ];
```

Input validation is not required. The output should look like a GridView (one key/value per line), but a GridView requires a model.

So I could use DynamicModel, ArrayDataProvider or other Yii2 stuff.

I tried a lot but there should be an easy way to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If you know the content of the array

You can do it this way and use the features of [DetailView](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-widgets#detail-view), esp. formating. I enhanced your data a little bit. Just copy the code into a view file to get a quick impression.

```
$myArray = [
   'name'             => 'bert',
   'age'              => 42,
   'My email address' => 'my-email@example.com', //no problems with spaces in the key
   'html'             => '<div style="font-size: 2em">asdf</div>',
];

echo \yii\widgets\DetailView::widget([
    'model'      => $myArray,
    'attributes' => [
        'name',
        'age',
        'My email address:email',
        'html',
        'html:html',
        'html:html:Html with different label',
        [
            'label'     => 'Html self defined',
            'attribute' => 'html', // key in model
            'format'    => 'raw'
        ]
    ]
])
```

Attributes refers to keys of the model.

Look [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-detailview#$attributes-detail) how you can use attributes.

## If the array is dynamic

i.e. you don't know the content and get different kind of data, you can use the DetailView default formatting (what means format is '[text](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#asText()-detail)'). In its simplest way it is:

```
echo \yii\widgets\DetailView::widget([
    'model'      => $myArray,
    'attributes' => array_keys($myArray),
]);
```

If you want to control the format more or less, use may want to use this, using format '[raw](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#asRaw()-detail)':

```
echo \yii\widgets\DetailView::widget([
    'model'      => $myArray,
    'attributes' => array_map(function ($key) {
        return "$key:raw"; 
        // or build some logic for the right format 
        // e.g. use '$key:email' if key contains 'email'
    }, array_keys($myArray)),
]);
```

Regarding the requirement in your answer of **localizing the labels** as well, you could do it this way (with default 'text' format):

```
echo \yii\widgets\DetailView::widget([
    'model'      => $myArray,
    'attributes' => array_map(function ($key) {
        return $key . ':text:' . Yii::t('app', 'label-' . $key);
    }, array_keys($myArray)),
]);
```

However, note some further logic could be needed if the `'label-' . $key` does not exist. Otherwise *label-somekey* would be shown in the DetailView.

Comment: This is no real solutions for my problem since the attributes to be displayed have to specified explicitly in DetailView. I need an arbitrary number of Key/Values in the array to be displayed in the view.

Comment: @WeSee Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks. that leads in the right directiony. in my solution there are labels handled, too. How can this be done in your  solution?

Comment: @WeSee In which way do/should they get handled?

Comment: please see my solution. each array should have a text label ‚label-key‘ which can be handled by Yii::t(...)

Comment: @WeSee Updated my answer with suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that even works with attribute labels being translated, but is it "the easiest"?

In controller file:

```
class MyDynModel extends \yii\base\DynamicModel {
    public function generateAttributeLabel($name) {
        return Yii::t('app','label-'.$name);
    }
}

class MyController extends Controller {
    public function actionShow() {
        $data = [ 'name' => 'bert', 'age' => 42 ];
        $dataModel = new MyDynModel($data);
        return $this->render('myview', ['dataModel'=>$dataModel]);
    }
}
```

In view file "my/myview.php":

```
echo \yii\widgets\DetailView::widget(['model'=>$dataModel]);
```

In translation file "messages/en/app.php":

```
return [
    'label-name' => 'Name',
    'label-age' => 'Age (in Years)',
];
```

Comment: IMHO it would be nice to make a callback function defining the labels. This would avoid subclassing the DynamicModel.

Comment: using ArrayDataProvider with gridview would be a simple and easy way to do it.

Comment: Ok, but a DetailView requires a model as data source AFAIK. How to bring this together?